# WSO2 MB 2.1 Error in deleting queue

Tags: jms, wso2, messagebroker

With Messagebroker 2.1 Messages sent to temporary queues seem to get undelivered.
More than that, I cannot delete these Objects in the Management Console.

Error in deleting queue. Cannot delete Queue : TempQueue6f42b522-351e-426f-ae9e-19a2ba215c4d javax.management.JMException: Queue "TempQueue6f42b522-351e-426f-ae9e-19a2ba215c4d" is not registered with the virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the tempQueue because the message sender is waiting for a response from the MB. If you are using an ESB Proxy Service you should have to use the following configuration to make the message "out only".

```
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" />
```

Then the MB tempQueue will be deleted automatically.